# How to add a Dom node created with JavaScript to vue using vue render functions

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, dom, vue-render-function

I have a JavaScript function that returns a DOM node that represents a tree view with many nested nodes inside it, I would like to know if it is possible to pass that function to vue render function ??

I know I should not be messing with the DOM or maybe instead use a recursive template, but for the sake of learning and challenge myself, I would still like to figure this out... how to manipulate the DOM within Vue, with the help of render functions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any mechanism to do this (at least not officially). The render function is not the place to manipulate the DOM in any way.

You can still manipulate the DOM *carefully* outside of the render function without bothering Vue too much. If you have a blank placeholder `<div>` in your template with a `ref`, then appending a child to it should be fine, as long as the DOM element remains in place (using `v-if` on the div may interfere, but I'm not 100% certain of this). Vue usually does a good job of reusing the same DOM element across re-renders – but that's the thing, you're messing with the DOM which Vue thinks it has complete control over, and you aren't guaranteed Vue will cooperate with any external changes to the DOM that it didn't expect.

Thinking about this a bit more, you can achieve what you want with a custom Vue directive or component. Something like this:

```js
Vue.directive('el', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    if (binding.value) {
      el.appendChild(binding.value)
    }
  },
  update(el, binding) {
    // Check if bound element changed
    if (binding.oldValue !== binding.newValue) {
      if (binding.oldValue) {
        // Remove old element
        binding.oldValue.remove()
      }
      if (binding.value) {
        // Append new element
        el.appendChild(binding.value)
      }
    }
  }
})

// Create a DOM element manually
const btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.textContent = 'Click'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render(h) {
    return h('div', {
      directives: [
        {
          name: 'el',
          value: btn
        }
      ]
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I have implemented you suggestion and it works, but I have been reading the Vue Docs to try to understand better render functions, and my question is:
Why cant we use something like this, to insert the the nodes we want into the dom ??
`domProps: {
    innerHTML: this.createTreeView()
  }`
Simple text works but not a function that returns a node
Thanks for your time

Comment: We can't do it because Vue doesn't allow it. This could potentially be something that Vue can do, but it currently isn't supported.